# Possible to use Generics defined in Generic definition

Tags: javascript, flowtype

I'm trying to use a generic defined within the generic definition of a class:

```
type Foo<T : BoundType> = {
    bar : T
}

class Class<F : Foo<T : BoundType>> {
    method(arg : T) { ... }
}
```

Flow complains about the syntax of `Class<F : Foo<T : BoundType>>`

Is there a way to use the T type used in Foo within the Class?  The following works, but I'm trying to remove the need for repeating the type twice:

```
type Foo<T : BoundType> = {
    bar : T
}

class Class<T : BoundType, F : Foo<T>> {
    method(arg : T) { ... }
}

let x = new Class<ConcreteType, Foo<ConcreteType>>;
```

Comment: Can you add the complaint please?

Comment: From the first block of code:
`class Class<F : Foo<T : BoundType>> {
                                       ^ T. Unexpected token :`

Comment: It would be easier to follow if you could produce a clear example in https://flow.org/try/. As it is, your example `new Class<ConcreteType, Foo<ConcreteType>>;` isn't valid in the first place, and we don't have examples of `ConcreteType` and `BoundType`.

Comment: Clarify expected relations between types please. Maybe you should give us an example with simple data, that shows what you expect

Comment: The code you have above looks like TypeScript and will not run in the browser. You will need to "compile" it to JavaScript.

Answer (score 0):

You can use [Existential Type (*)](https://flow.org/en/docs/types/utilities/#toc-existential-type) to tell Flow to infer the generic type parameter, and [$ElementType](https://flow.org/en/docs/types/utilities/#toc-elementtype) to "query" `bar` property type:

```
type Foo<T : BoundType> = {
    bar : T
}

class TestClass<F : Foo<*>> {
    method(arg : $ElementType<F, 'bar'>) { }
}

declare var c: TestClass<Foo<ConcreteType>>;
```

[Try it here](https://flow.org/try/#0PQKgBAAgZgNg9gdzCYAoVAXAngBwKZgDCcAdgMYBOeGeAKrgQLxgDeYAhgFxgkCuAtgCM8FADRhB3PkJEBfANyYGYAEJxeJACb18YZmy48BwimFnpsugGJw4AHlphuajdoYA+Pa1RhfE9qbctKjmqGQw7ADOkWC0eJEYhBHRdlZOYDb2IO6eLD5+-NQAFnCaABQBAObpACQAojB4hSQYOnip4gDkggGd7gCUrGYh6Jp44QEEAG4BYGRB8YnJkam2dsTkVDRtOYphAHSFGCXlBtwAjOKSYOey-XvAwGD1AB74ZBh1FBRwFAdHJzKACZ7kA)

** There might be a better way to get type of generic type parameter rather than querying `bar` property type.

*** Renamed `Class` to `TestClass` because [Class](https://flow.org/en/docs/types/utilities/#toc-class) is one of the flow's utilities, so I suggest you to not to use it as name.